# Get last added record id in entity framework with postgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Students table has id ,name , gender,address columns. id is the identity column. when each student details added to this table  using  below lines of code,

```
 _dataContext.Students.Add(student);
_dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

I need to get last inserted id value. this id value I need to insert to other table say 'Subject' table as studentid column.

How can I get last inserted id ?

Comment: You already did. EF Core detects all modifications to the objects it tracks and persists all of them in a single transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. `SaveChanges` is essentially a `Commit()` call and should only be called at the very end of a unit of work/business transaction. `SaveChanges` will save all changes for all new or modified objects, retrieve the new IDs for the new objects and fix up relations. After it, `student.Id` should have the new value, along with any other new class related to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already the `Id`. `SaveChanges` takes care of retrieving the IDs and fixing up relations for all the objects it persists.

A DbContext detects all modifications to the objects it tracks and persists all of them in a single transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. `SaveChanges` is essentially a `Commit()` call and should only be called at the very end of a unit of work/business transaction.

`SaveChanges` will save all changes for all new or modified objects, retrieve the new IDs for the new objects and fix up relations. After it, `student.Id` should have the new value, along with any other new class related to it.

This means you could write the following code to persist a new course and students, and get back the IDs for all of them.

```
var course=new Course(...);
foreach(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    course.Students.Add(new Student(...));
}

context.Courses.Add(course);

context.SaveChanges();

Console.WriteLine($"Course ID: {course.Id}");
foreach(var s in course.Students)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Student ID: {s.Id}");    
}
```

The `DbSet.Add` method add both the root course and *all* reachable objects to the DbContext in the `Added` state. All of these will be saved by `SaveChanges`.

If you want to discard the changes, just don't call `SaveChanges`. When the DbContext gets disposed, the changes will be lost too.

That explains why all the non-"repository" CRUD classes are so badly broken. A method like this :

```
public int BadInsert(Student student)
{
    _context.Students.Add(student);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Has no way of rolling back the possibly dozens of DELETEs, UPDATE and INSERTs it may execute beyond the single Student. You'd have to explicitly open a connection and start a long-running transaction to be able to roll back that Student if something goes wrong.

Answer (score -2):

SELECT timestamp, value, card
FROM my_table
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1

Comment: That's wrong in all database products and unrelated to the actual question. This doesn't return the new ID at all